# A Global Key was used multiple times inside one widget's child list

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

Getting a error in flutter = 1. A Global Key was used multiple times inside one widget's child list and Could not find a generator for route Route Settings("/", null) in the _Widgets App State ,cant understand what to do in this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN8BM.png)

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet instead of code-image that will reproduce the same error

Comment: In particular, show every use of GlobalKey() in your app.